# PHP- "else" gets executed even when there is another "elseif" for what i'm trying to do

Tags: php

i am trying to make this in php:

```
        <?php
        $link = $_GET['link'];
        $sayi = strlen($link);
        $list = array(something here)
        if (in_array($link, $list)) 
        {
          some code here 1
        }
        elseif($sayi == "0")
        {
          some code here 2
        }
        if($sayi != "11" AND $sayi != "0")
        {
          some code here 3  
        }
        else
        {
          some code here 4  
        }
?>
```

when i try with a blank $link, it should normally execute only "some code here 2". i don't understand my mistake but it executes both "some code here 2" and "some code here 4".

what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance, i'm pretty new to php (is 2 days new? :)).

god, i feel very idiot. i'll accept your answer when i can (time limit)

Comment: In second if you check `$sayi` which has integer. strlen returns int (http://php.net/strlen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 separated pieces of code being evaluated, one `IF` with its `ELSEIF`, and then another `IF` with its own `ELSE`. You must make consecutive `ELSEIFs` if you want to check one condition only once.

```
$link = $_GET['link'];
        $sayi = strlen($link);
        $list = array(something here)
        if (in_array($link, $list)) 
        {
          some code here 1
        }
        elseif($sayi == 0)
        {
          some code here 2
        }
        elseif($sayi != 11 AND $sayi != 0)
        {
          some code here 3  
        }
        else // If NONE of previous conditional is true, then execute this.
        {
          some code here 4  
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate if conditions, and as per your code the output is right. you have to change the code to below

```
if (in_array($link, $list)) 
        {
          some code here 1
        }
        elseif($sayi == "0")
        {
          some code here 2
        }
        else if($sayi != "11" AND $sayi != "0")// add else here
        {
          some code here 3  
        }
        else
        {
          some code here 4  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the second if with elseif like so:

```
<?php

$link = $_GET['link'];
$sayi = strlen($link);
$list = array(something here)
if (in_array($link, $list)) 
{
  some code here 1
}
elseif($sayi == 0)
{
  some code here 2
}
elseif($sayi != 11)
{
  some code here 3  
}
else
{
  some code here 4  
}
```

Another hint: strlen returns int, so you don't need the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ? 
First of all you should use the comparison as in "if ($sayi == 0)"  . And even after that for "$sayi == 11"   or for  "$sayi == 0" ,  always "some code here 4" will be printed.